# Cannot upload created shapefile

Tags: shapefile, javascript, error, africa

I cannot upload my Africa shapefiles that I created in QGIS (where I dissolved all internal boundaries), why?

I get this error when I run my code with some Africa shapefiles (which are not dissolved) `"Dictionary (Error) Collection.geometry: Geometry has too many edges (2339553 > 2000000)."`

Link to the asset: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/fredlink9/Africa_Boundaries.

This is the code:

```
var filtered = chirps.filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-01-01', '2018-01-01'))
var total = filtered.sum().clip(Africa)
var palette = ['white', 'blue']
var visParams = {
  min: 0,
  max:2000,
  palette: palette
}
Map.addLayer(total, visParams, 'Total Rainfall')

//Calculate average rainfall in bKhartoum
var stats = total.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
 geometry: Africa.geometry()
 , scale: 5000
})
print(stats)
//print(stats.get('precipitation'))
```

Comment: where are you trying to upload the shapefiles to?